# Initiate PHP scripts with heavy SQL calls when server load is low?

Tags: php, triggers

Do I use CRON to do this, or is there some other system?  I have never done this before, but I would like to run some PHP scripts when the server load dies down and pause the scripts from running if the server load picks up.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the PHP process with a high nice value, e.g. 19 - that way, it only gets processing time when no other process needs it.

For example, use

```
$ nice -n 19 php path/to/your/php/script.php
```

on your shell.

You can also use php's renice functionality: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-nice.php

Comment: I'm not sure what the process is, or nice values... but I can look up nice values.

Comment: Hmmm.  Could you tell me if it's PHP, the PHP script, or SQL that is the process?

Comment: Are you running you Script as CLI or Apache / CGI?

Comment: @Tim, I suppose I'm using it as CLI because I'm not sure how to use CGI, but I do have Apache installed.

Comment: Is there any alternative for a shared host?

Comment: what does "shared host" implicate to you? No shell access? No cron?